# Is it possible to get strand count?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I currently have a strand that perform jobs for me in a linear order. I wanted to know if there was a way to get the no. of jobs in the queue of the strand.

Comment: I suspect not (but I don't know for sure, so this isn't an answer) since there's no way to get a reliable answer. Another thread could have posted a job between your thread examining the queue and acting on the information.

Comment: The private memeber of strand (i think is called member) has the count in it. But its not accessible

Comment: What version of Boost.Asio are you using?  From Boost 1.35 to 1.53, I cannot recall `strand` having a member containing the size of its operation queue.

Comment: I am using Boost 1.47 - 32 bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way as [`strand`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html) neither provides a public means to access the information nor directly contains a count.  If you access the private member variables, then it would be possible to obtain the size via `count_` within `strand::impl_`.

Alternative approaches include:

- Wrapping the `strand`, providing a similar API that increments and decrements counts.  This new type would need to wrap any handlers being posted, as it needs to inject a hook to decrementing the count once the user's handler finishes execution.
- Create a functor object that increments a count during its construction, and decrements a count during destruction.  All handlers being posted or dispatched through a strand would be wrapped by the functor.